# How to remove mysql data from html delete button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a list of items and each one has a delete button, but nothing happens when I press it. The database is connected because it displays the items in the table, but I have no idea why the delete buttons aren't working. If anyone sees the error, please let me know. Thanks so much. Also, this is my first website so my code is messy for now.

> Note: I do close the database so that's not a problem.

**user.php**:

```
<?php
$user_id = '999';
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="root";
$dbname="peas";
 $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket) or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
//continued 

<div style: "height:1000px; class="col-md-3" id="ingredients">
    <ul class="list-group" style="max-height:900px; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x: hidden">
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT  ingredient_name FROM Ingredient";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   ?>
                   <li style="text-align: left; padding:10px" 
                    class="list-group-item">
                            <form action="user_functions.php" method="post">
                                <?php echo $row['ingredient_name'];?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="ingredient_name" value= "<?php $row['$ingredient_name']; ?>">
                                <button type="button" name="delete" style="float:right; border:none;">&times;</button>
                            </form>
                    </li>
            <?php }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else{
                echo "<li>"."Pantry is Empty!"."</li>";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**user_functions.php**:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $ingredient_name=$_POST['ingredient_name'];
        $sql="DELETE FROM ingredient WHERE ingredient_name=$ingredient_name";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: There is no need of html and css tag.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your HTML code to this:

```
<form action="user_functions.php" method="post">
    <?php echo $row['ingredient_name'];?>
    <input type="hidden" name="ingredient_name" value="<?php echo $row['$ingredient_name']; ?>">
    <button type="submit" name="delete" style="float:right; border:none;">&times</button>
</form>
```

and edit `user_functions.php` to this:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['ingredient_name'])){
        $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM ingredient WHERE ingredient_name=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['ingredient_name']);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to not submit form on press <kbd>×</kbd>
then you should change `button type="submit"`

```
<form action="user_functions.php" method="post">
    <?php echo $row['ingredient_name'];?>
    <input type="hidden" name="ingredient_name" value="<?php $row['$ingredient_name']; ?>">
    <button type="submit" name="delete" style="float:right; border:none;">&times</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="hidden" name="ingredient_name" value="<?php $row['$ingredient_name']; ?>">
```

Two things

1. You are showing value wrongly in above input it should be
   `$row['ingredient_name']` remove the `$` inside the brackets plus also
   you should echo it.

   so it should be `<?php echo $row['ingredient_name'];?>`
2. You have to use button type as `Submit` and not `button` form will
       not be submitted if there is not button type submit.

Answer (score -1):

Beside other two answers, there is another problem.

If the code in user_function.php you shown us is everything in your user_function.php, variable $db does not exist in user_function.php.

Therefore, you need to separate the connection and HTML into two file (e.g. config.php, user.php) and include or require config.php to user_function.php. i.e.

config.php:

```
<?php
$user_id = '999';
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="root";
$dbname="peas";
 $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket) or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

user_function.php:

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $ingredient_name=$_POST['ingredient_name'];
        $sql="DELETE FROM ingredient WHERE ingredient_name=$ingredient_name";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    }
?>
```